# How can I check the state of the DataContext connection in LINQ to SQL?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq-to-sql, razor

I want to know the state of the connection of the LINQ to SQL context.

I tried like this `db.Connection.State`.

I want to check the connection state of the database context and populate a message in my View in mvc3.

Comment: This isn't making much sense, sorry. What is the state you are looking for? If the LINQ2SQL context is "working"?

Answer (score 1):

The [db.Connection.State property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbconnection.state.aspx) returns a string that describes the state of the connection. It does not really make sense to pass that to your view, except maybe for some experiment.

Knowing it is a string, it should not be more difficult than returning "Hello, world!".

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewData["HelloName"] = db.Connection.State;
    return View();
}
```